# Any better ways to deal with Facebook Sdk still using Android support libraries with version=27.0.2?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

The main `androidSupportVersion` that I want to use in my project is `27.1.1` but 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.0.0' still fix dependency version to `27.0.2`. That causes dependency collision in the project.

For now this piece of code comes with work-around solution by excluding one collided dependency called `cardview-v7`.

```
dependencies {
    def androidSupportVersion = '27.1.1'
    def withoutCardView = {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    }

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$androidSupportVersion", withoutCardView
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.0.0'
}
```